# Text/terminal-based screen sharing program

Tags: linux, debian, terminal-emulator, screen-sharing

I'm not happy with screen-sharing capabilities of some instant messaging programs used in my company, especially because most of the time I need to share just a terminal, and not images/GUI stuff.

Therefore I am looking for a program that would help me on that.

Since a program exists, [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/), that does text/terminal-based recording, I'm wondering if there's a program to do the sharing of the terminal via internet.

I'm on Linux Debian 10 and use the Bash shell in Debian's default terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for your use case.

- Visual Studio Code Plugin Live Share (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare)
- https://tmate.io/
- https://tty-share.com/

tmate and tty-share are more native for the VS Code Plugin you obviously need VS Code ;-)

happy coding & have fun

Comment: As a side question, given I suspect that launching `tty-share` doesn't have _any_ overhead until I actually open the link; do you think this is the case? A similar question holds I guess also for the other alternatives: is there any overhead in making the session available before anyone actually looks at it?

Comment: It looks to me that if you launch tty-share in your terminal session it will send the session to your tty-share server not matter if someone is connected or not.